# Install interior camera on an exterior wall.

Tags: electrical, wiring, security

I am installing a Camera system, 2 story house, However I need to install one of the cameras on an exterior wall on the inside of the house. I have no way to gain access to the attic space at the wall. My question is, is there a way to mount this camera any way and fish the wire up to the attic without removing sheetrock or will I need to drill all the way through the outside of the house and go up through the eaves that way. By the way the location of the camera is on a one story side of the house. So there is attic space above wall.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is cheat and drill a hole through both the interior and exterior walls. You'll need an extra long drill bit and make sure there's no electrical in the way (i.e. identify where the studs are and where the outlets are).

Be sure to caulk the outside hole with an exterior grade caulk